# Canon multipass c555 printer driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have windows 7 in my laptop, i want to use canon multipass c555 printer but there is no driver available to use. while i used driver for mentioned win xp which is not working in win7 . please help how to install my printer in win7 , is any software available

Answer (score 0):

Vista drivers sometimes work on Windows 7